# Rejected Client-Certificate in Chrome 61

Tags: google-chrome, openssl, client-certificates

I have an already long running website secured by self generated client-certificates. It has been working for years without any problems with any browser like IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Since the last Chrome Update (61.0.3163.100) the client certificates are rejected with following error message:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

my.domain.com didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided.
Try contacting the system admin.
ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
```

And the site continues to work fine with any other browser!
And i can not find any relevant information out there.

I assume that chrome just raised the minimal requirements for the client certificates, as it did for server certificates a few months ago. but i have no glue how to fix it.

Any hint what is wrong with my certificates?

many thanks

## UPDATE 15DEC2017

I still had problems and did not find any answer out there.

After a while i figured out that Chrome does not like the Client Certificates generated by `openssl ca`.

I was generating the Certificates so:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions client -batch -in test.req -out test.cer
```

I tried everything but i was not able to make it to work with Chrome, but again, it worked with all other Browsers.

Now i am generating the Certificates so:

```
openssl x509 -req -in test.req -CA ca.cer -CAkey ca.key -extensions client -extfile openssl.cnf -CAserial ca.srl -out test.cer -sha256
```

And it works, if i compare the out of `openssl x509 -in test.cer -noout -text`, there is **NO** difference!! So i am wondering what Chrome does not like of `openssl ca`.

I would prefer to use `openssl ca` over `openssl x509` since i can not use CRLs and i prefer also `startdate/enddate` over `days`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was generating the Certificates so:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions client -batch -in test.req -out test.cer
```

I tried everything but i was not able to make it to work with Chrome, but again, it worked with all other Browsers.

Now i am generating the Certificates so:

```
openssl x509 -req -in test.req -CA ca.cer -CAkey ca.key -extensions client -extfile openssl.cnf -CAserial ca.srl -out test.cer -sha256
```

And it works!

if i compare the out of `openssl x509 -in test.cer -noout -text`, there is **NO** difference!! So i am wondering what Chrome does not like of `openssl ca`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on it from this website:https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TM0Tg0_YOvg

To solve this issue this :
try these steps ;
1) Rest browser by clearing out all data in internet options of IE..
2) Remove all certificates related to site you are trying access...Chrome shares IE cert
3) make sure that you have internet access afterwards.. if not check proxy settings if it applies
4) try to go to the same site again and if it prompts for certificate insert smart card or install cert.
5) if it does not work you can remove all certs from personal but be careful removing certs form intermediate and else where.

This error is the certificate has an problem on the local machine you are using.
for DOD users see https://militarycac.com/dodcerts.htm   if there are more issues..I am able using the steps I posted to access DOD sites.. make sure you have installroot3a   exe installed as well